# What is Contextual Embedding?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, natural-language, word2vec, word-embeddings

I understand word embeddings and word2vec.

In this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01547.pdf

they are saying a new type of word embedding.

> ```
> Our model uses one word embedding function
> and two encoder functions. The word embedding
> function e translates words into vector representations.
> The first encoder function is a document
> encoder f that encodes *every word from the document*
> d *in the context of the whole document*.
> We call this the **contextual embedding**.
> ```

Is this some new way of encoding, How can I implement this? Thanks .

Comment: Where do they claim it's a new type of word embedding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The contextual embedding of a word is just the corresponding hidden state of a bi-GRU:

> In our model the document encoder $f$ is implemented as **a bidirectional Gated Recurrent Unit (GRU) network whose hidden states form the contextual word embeddings**, that is $f_i(d) = \overrightarrow{f_i}(d) \,\, ||\,\, \overleftarrow{f_i}(d)$, where $||$ denotes vector concatenation and $\overrightarrow{f_i}$ and $\overleftarrow{f_i}$ denote forward and backward contextual embeddings from the respective recurrent networks.

In red is the contextual embedding of the first word:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I do not understand why is it called contextutal embedding? Does it really capture the context?

Comment: @SieTw Yes, it captures the context, since the hidden states are computed based on the previous hidden states.

Comment: source of the diagram?